# How can I use a Windows command to grant a read permission to a particular user id for a certificate private key on local machine in MMC

Tags: windows, command-line, permissions, certificate, private-key

How can I use a Windows command line to grant a read permission to a particular user id for a certificate private key on local machine in MMC, which is to replace following manual steps?

*Create a Microsoft Management Console (MMC) with the Certificates snap-in that targets the Local Machine certificate store.
Expand the MMC and select Manage Private Keys.
On the Security tab, add the Network Service account with Read access.*

I am not able to find any option in CertUtil. Can anyone please help with me?

Thank you so much!

Jun